# jQuery Slide Toggle Menu doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

i find it strange. I couldn't figure it out why.

First of all, I put js files on the `<head>`. Something like this below:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js"></script>`

Furthermore, my code for menu navigation like below:

For HTML

```
<ul class="mainMenu">
      <li>LINK 1
          <ul class="subMenu">
            <li>SUB LINK 1</li>
            <li>SUB LINK 2</li>
            <li>SUB LINK 3</li>
            <li>SUB LINK 4</li>
           </ul>
      </li>
      <li> LINK 2 </li>
    </ul>
```

For JS:

`$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.mainMenu').children('li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow'); 
    });
}`

AND CSS:

`.subMenu {
    display: none;
}`

Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2ezsP/70/). It is working in JSFiddle but it's not working in my server. I am wondering why. Any idea?

Comment: first load <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

Comment: @Bala okay, I tried it and it still doesn't work. Can you have a look the updated question as I remodify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the case or not. You must put your code inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // here });
```

So your are telling jQuery to load/manipulate dom elements after all the HTML elements has been loaded.

Now here comes the point that why is your [***your fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/2ezsP/70/) is working.

> Its because, ***$(document).ready(function(){ });*** it's already built-in inside the js panal of jsFiddle. So whatever jQuery you write on that panel it all will go inside ***$(document).ready(function() { // here })*** which means all your code will run after the page has finished loading.

**Note :** *And of course maintain order when loading the scripts accordingly as you don't want to call a function that hasn't been loaded yet for sure.*

Comment: Can you check the updated question again? I did as you asked me to do. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Oh ya I missed the last quotes. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

Should be loaded first

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

When jQuery is loaded, load other components

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: okay, I tried it and it still doesn't work. Can you have a look the updated question as I remodify the question.

Answer (score 0):

First load jquery , jquery  migrate is plugin so load after jquery framework

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js"></script>
```

wrap the code in document ready

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('.mainMenu').children('li').on('click', function() {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow'); 
        });
    });  
___ ^--- not close
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Below code and just try it again, It should work or not ??

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('.mainMenu').children('li').on('click', function() {
         $(.subMenu).css("display", "block");
         $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow'); 
   });
});
```